# SQL similar subqueries, where clause slight difference

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a more optimal way of optimising a query which contains multiple subqueries that all select the same attributes.

Similar to the following:

```
  (select column1,column3 from server_data where column2='System Model') m
, (select column1,column3 from server_data where column2='Machine Serial Number')s
, (select column1,column3 from server_data where column2='Host Name')n
, (select column1,column3 from server_data where column2='Mode')mo
WHERE s.column1=m.column1(+)
    AND s.column1=mo.column1(+)
    AND s.column1=n.column1(+)
```

Comment: (System Model,Machine Serial Number,Host Name,Mode) you want all values must be available or any of them must be available ?

Comment: What happens to the columns? Do you want to pivot your data? Can you provide a complete select please?

Comment: It's below as an answer the whole query

Comment: Please stop using Oracles outdated `(+)` syntax for outer joins. Even Oracle recommends to not use it.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you making unnessary `join` with the same table. If i got you correct you need something like

```
 SELECT column1, column3
  FROM server_data
 WHERE column2 IN ('System Model',
                   'Machine Serial Number',
                   'Host Name',
                   'Mode')
```

Comment: I dont think that where in condition is working here because he need to check  all values are  available or not. but in your query when ever any one value is available then it will show that selected record only.

Comment: As far i observed and understood this should work. Rest i leave it to OP to evaluate if this works or not.

Comment: Maybe a PIVOT clause is needed. Unfortunately the OP did not show us the full query.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Unfortunately due to lack of complete query and expected output all I could come up is the above one. May be OP add few more clarifcation later on

Comment: They are joining data side by side, this just dumps rows. This doesn't cater for outer joins

Comment: @AbBennett First you need to understand wheather outer join is actually needed or not. Secondly, from my point its not needed. Also if you want several columns in select list side by sied then you need to write thos in select statement which i cannot see in actual statement, However am not sure what OP wants

Answer (score 0):

Use a with statement / cte at the top of query which selects all the data from Server_data where column2 is in one of the 4 values, then use the cute alias 4 times in the select. This should improve performance. Plus depending on selectivity create index on column2

```
With dat as 
( select * from server_data where column2 in (...,...,...,...) 
)
Select * from dat Dat_sysmodel, dat dat_mode
where dat_Sysmodel.column2 = 'System Model'
And   Dat_mode.column2 = 'Mode'
And   Dat_sysmodel.id = dat_mode.id (+)
```

Sorry I am on iPad so hard to type it completely

Comment: So the second select statement would contain sysmodel, dat_mode, something for host name and serial number? followed by the relevant WHERE joins?

Comment: Yes , this would achieve what u have above but faster, just doing one scan of larger table, and then just using what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each `column1` has at most one match, I would use conditional aggregation:

```
select column1,
       max(case when column2 = 'System Model' then column3 end) as system_model,
       max(case when column2 = 'Machine Serial Number' then column3 end) as machine_serial_number,
       max(case when column2 = 'Host Name' then column3 end) as host_name,
       max(case when column2 = 'Mode' then column3 end) as mode
from server_data
group by column1;
```

I find the logic much easier to follow.  In addition, this does not use deprecated join syntax.  A piece of advise:  Stop using commas in the `FROM` clause.  Proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax is more powerful.

Comment: I have since rewritten to incorporate this and it is indeed a lot cleaner. Only issue is that it leaves behind some null values

Comment: @user3208158 . . . You can remove rows with `NULL` values using a `having` clause.

Comment: So in the example above, what would the clause look like? setting it to column1 returns no values

Comment: `having max(case when column2 = 'Machine Serial Number' then column3 end) is not null`

Comment: This worked, more of a general question but how could this be altered if say column1 had to be distinct in one case, or say an additional attribute had to be returned in a condition?